# ¿Cómo obtener el ID del objeto por medio de una CreateView Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-urls, django-views, django-class-based-views

La consulta es como obtener el ID del objeto que se creo por medio de una `CreateView` en `Django`, el problema radica en que tengo 2 modelos:

`Factura` y `Detalle` los cuales están relacionados, y no logre hacer un formulario `inline` para mostrar en la vista, así que pienso lo siguiente:

Primero se creara el objeto `Factura` y luego capturar el ID redirecionar a un `CreateView` pero de `Detalle` y por medio del ID de la `Factura` crear los objetos que formaran el `Detalle`, no se si se podrá realizar de esta forma, o es mas sencillo realizar un formulario `inline` para este caso..? tengo poca experiencia en `Django` y `MVT` les agradezco su ayuda.

Archivo `views.py`:

```
# Vista de Factura

@method_decorator(staff_member_required, name='dispatch')
class OrdenCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Pedido
    form_class = PedidoForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Plist')

# Vista del Detalle
class DetalleCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "TEMPLATE_NAME"
```

Archivo `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Pedido

class PedidoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Pedido
        fields = ['id', 'cliente', 'pago', 'tipo_pago']
        widgets = {
            'id': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': "form-control mb-3",
                }),
            'cliente': forms.Select(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control mb-3',
                'placeholder': 'Cliente'}),
            'pago': forms.Select(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control mb-3',
                'placeholder': 'Pago'}),
            'tipo_pago': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control mb-3',
                'placeholder': 'Tipo de Pago'}),
        }
        labels = {
            'title': '', 'order': '',
        }
```

Comment: Cuál es tu problema en hace un inline?

Comment: Sinceramente que no he trabajo con formularios inline en las vistas para mi eso seria lo mas optimo, sin embargo no tengo ese conocimiento y no he encontrado información que me pueda ayudar a resolver esa duda.

Comment: Fíjate en esta respuesta amigo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497684/django-class-based-views-with-inline-model-form-or-formset

Comment: te sugiero revisar : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13310257/5215609

Answer (score 0):

El contexto , o sea los datos del objeto que estas creando , listando, o modificando viajan con la data de una pagina a otra. Solo debes reescribir el metodo get_context_data en tus vistas basadas en clases.

ej:

```
class MiVista(DetailView):
    def get_contetx_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        #luego agregas al contexto lo que desees que vaya a la otra pagina o se use en esta.
        context['los_datos que quieras del objeto'] = 'aca van los datos o queryset'
        return context
```